# make url pretty in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using node.js with express & mongoose to build a simple blog site. Up on clicking on a particular blog post, it will redirect to the show page with the url as follows: http://localhost/HomeCooking/58be64778811460ace2d4ca0

In order to make this url human understandable, can I use my blog title instead? Or is there any other way of making the url pretty.

```
app.get("/HomeCooking/:id", function(req, res)
     {
          CookingRecipe.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCookingRecipe){
            if(err){console.log(err);}
            else
            {
            res.render("show", {CookingRecipe: foundCookingRecipe});
            }
     });

});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sure, you can use the title. With the title in the URL parameter, you should be able to look it up using something like `CookingRecipe.find({title: req.params.title, ... })`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Building on the above, create a slug of a unique field, can be title, name and use those slugs for creating urls.

Comment: Perfect.. Thank you @SwarajGiri